# Lua pattern in mqtt topics

Tags: lua, lua-patterns

Here is a standard topic pattern which is used in mqtt.

```
"lights/hue/{device_name}/get/sensing"
```

How could I use the regular expression to format this topic pattern with a real device name.

I am not very into the regular expression, so what I would need is a function to make a topic given a device name.

for example,

```
pattern : "lights/hue/{device_name}/get/sensing"
input : name = 'device123'
output: "lights/hue/device123/get/sensing"
```

Currently I am using the lua, would someone help me?

Comment: Please show what you tried and please limit to one language. Since you are not using Swift/Objective-C, the `nsregularexpression` tag can be removed.

Comment: What's your desired in- and output?

Comment: the example is shown above.

Comment: `var output = s.replace("{device_name}", name)` - haven't you really tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Lua:

```
pattern = "lights/hue/{device_name}/get/sensing"
name = "device123"
output = string.gsub(pattern, "{device_name}", name )
print(output)
```

There is no need for a regular expression. Simple replacement will do the job.